# How can I filter subnet by ID for Ec2 CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

I'm looking for a way to filter a subnet by Id, from the docs seems like we can use SubnetFilter but I can't parse the subnetFilter to a SubnetSelection:

```
// Err: Initializer type Subnetfilter Is not assignable to variable type SubnetSelection
const subnets = ec2.SubnetSelection = ec2.SubnetFilter.byIds("subnet-id");

const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'vpc', {
  vpcName: vpc,
  subnets: subnets,
});
```

I looked into this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/12848) but couldn't figure out how to implement it, also tried with ISubnets but haven't found a working example to reference from and believe me I've looked. Sorry if it's a dumb Typescript missunderstanding

Comment: What is your goal here? If you already have the subnet ID in hand, perhaps you could just use [ec2.Subnet.fromSubnetId(...)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Subnet.html#static-fromwbrsubnetwbridscope-id-subnetid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a cloud-side lookup of the existing VPC:

```js
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'vpc', {
  vpcName: 'my-vpc',
});
```

Call its [selectSubnets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Vpc.html#selectwbrsubnetsselection) method, passing the `subnetFilters` option:

```js
const selection: ec2.SubnetSelection = vpc.selectSubnets({
    subnetFilters: [ec2.SubnetFilter.byIds(["subnet-id"])],
});
```